# custom tag timeout error in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I have a calling page (abc.cfm), scheduled as a task. It has a custom tag call which does cfhttp calls and scrapes the websites. Now the job is failing due to request timeout issues. I am trying to do a `<cftry> <cfcatch>` around the custom tag call, like shown below.

On a timeout I need to reschedule this job. I have created a test target with an unreachable url =http://www.google.com:81/. So the custom tag will hit this page and timeout. However I do not see a scheduled task being created in cfadmin. Is there anything I'm missing here?

```
<cftry>    

  <cf_main-test target_id="#thistid#" crawl_id="#crawl_id#" fullrunmode=false>

  <cfcatch type="any"> 

    <cfset tock = GetTickCount()>
    <cfset time = tock-tick>

    <cfschedule 
      url="http://10.0.0.100/engine/testauto.cfm?task=yes&LastTaskID=#taskID#&nexttid=#thistid#" 
      action="update" 
      task="process item #TaskID#" 
      operation="httprequest"
      startdate="#DateFormat(Now(),'mm/dd/yyyy')#" 
      starttime="#TimeFormat(DateAdd('n', 1, Now()),'hh:mm:ss tt')#"
      interval="once">


  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

example cfhttp call :

```
<CFHTTP url="#pagetoscrape#" method="GET" path="#savepath#" file="#savedfilename#" resolveurl="#resolveurl#" useragent="User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)#Chr(13)##Chr(10)#Accept: */*#Chr(13)##Chr(10)#Cookie: #lwwcookie#" timeout="20">
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is dropping into the cfcatch block?

Comment: it is not, I just added a <cfmail> to see if it would email me, but it did not go through. that is why I am wondering, if there is any other way of catching a timeout error from that custom tag. But i can making a cfhttp call to http://www.google.com:81/ from the custom tag, so it needs to error and come through the cfcatch. thanks for looking.

Comment: Examine the CFHTTP structure. I think you can probably key off of an HTTP error code (408 timeout, for instance). Or, at the very least, if you don't get a "200 OK" back, `cfthrow` an error for your cfcatch to pick up.

Comment: Also, what does your cfhttp call look like?

Comment: Updated the code, since my custom tag has many cfhttp calls, should i use <cfthrow> on every call to return to calling page?

Comment: Looking at the documentation on cfthrow will help you decide if that's a good idea for this situation.

Comment: *..email me, but it did not go through* Re-read the documentation for `cfhttp`. The default is [`throwOnError="no"`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html), meaning it will NOT throw an exception if an error occurs. That said, it sounds like the process is trying to do [too much at one time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526875/scheduled-crawler-in-coldfusion). You should consider breaking it into smaller batches.

Comment: I updated throwonerror="yes" on the cfhttp calls, still the cfcatch does not catch any exception...any comments pls?

Comment: Put together a *minimal* [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue. *RE: still the cfcatch does not catch any exception* In the comments below, [you said it "errors"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571632/custom-tag-timeout-error-in-coldfusion#comment36255532_23576482). If you are already catching exceptions *inside* the custom tag, they will not bubble up to the outer `cfcatch` clause. But again, it sounds like the process is trying to do too much and should be broken down into small batches.

Answer (score -2):

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="900" />
```

Put that in the tag.  To expent the page request timeout ( for that page only )

Comment: I added this on the custom tag, if the target is timing out it is just stopping there and erroring, I want to be able to catch the error.